# Is it possible to put two title pics?

Tags: titles

I wanted to know if it is possible to put two title pics on the front page of a report?

```
\title{Title}
\author{X}
\date{}
\titlepic{\includegraphics [width=10cm]{logo_1}}
\titlepic{\includegraphics [width=10cm]{logo_2}}
```

When I do this only {logo_2} is showed on the front page. I would like to put one on the top of the title and one on the bottom. Is this possible?

Comment: Just found how to do it!

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities, both of which entail placing two images within the argument of a single `\titlepic` invocation.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[tt]{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Title}
\author{X}
\date{}
\titlepic{\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-b}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[tt]{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Title}
\author{X}
\date{}
\titlepic{\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-a}\\[2pt]
\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-b}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]